# iOS 14.0.1 crash issue

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

Since last release on the AppStore, that was a major update, with many new sections and two new targets added to project, my app started crashing on iOS 14.0.1 only on various devices.
No issues with all other OS.
Many users report the app is crashing at launch, showing a black screen and then crashing.
In Xcode organizer I can see all empty crash logs, with no stack trace.
I have no chance to replicate the issue since I have no device with iOS 14.0.1 and have no idea what could have introduced the issue and, most of all, what kind of issue can affect iOS 14.0.1 only.
Any idea or suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: do you load the first view controller programmatically ? maybe something related to the new scene delegate?

Comment: The app uses UIKit and has no SceneDelegate. It uses AppDelegate and the last release didn’t apply any change related to app launch.

Comment: No error logs.  No stack trace.  You’re almost certainly going to have to get a device with iOS 14.0.1 and debug it there. Or add logic to detect that it’s running on 14.0.1 and display an error message requiring users to upgrade.  But you’ll still need a device to test out your error message.